# React site items are not clickable and elements are overlapping in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I've seen issues like this but haven't found a definitive fix -- All links/buttons on my react app when run on IE11 are unclickable, and some items are overlapping. Is there a fix for this?

This is what the ie console puts out: [image: out]

Comment: You probably have to configure babel to output javascript that is compatible with ie11, since that browser does not support ES6 syntax. Unfortunately Babel has changed its API quite frequently, so many answers about babel here on StackOverflow are outdated. It might be better to just read the Babel docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following meta tag in the head section of your index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Besides, please check your code and refer to the following steps to make sure it has imported the react-app-polyfill:

1. Install the package using Yarn or npm:

   ```
   npm install react-app-polyfill
   ```

   or

   ```
   yarn add react-app-polyfill
   ```
2. Add the following code at the first line in 'src/index.js'.

   ```
   import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
   import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
   ```
3. Add ie 11 in 'packge.json' like this:

   ```
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all",
         "ie 11"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version",
         "ie 11"
       ]
     }
   ```
4. Restart the app and it will work in IE11.

Finally, if still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).